# Selenium, Xpath, select a certain part of text within a node

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have a source file like this:

```
<div class="l_post j_l_post l_post_bright  " ...>
<div class="lzl_cnt">
 ...
 <span class="lzl_content_main">
  text1
     <a class="at j_user_card" username="...">
       username
     </a>
  text3
 </span>
</div>
...
</div>
```

And I want to get **text3**, Currently, I tried this:(I am at `<div class="lzl_cnt">`)

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'.//span[@class="lzl_content_main"]/text()[1]')
```

but I got

> "Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression
>   ".//span[@class="lzl_content_main"]/text()[1]" is: [object Text]. It
>   should be an element".

And Is there a way to get the `"text3"`?

**I should make it clearer:**

The above HTML is part of the bigger structure, and I selected it out with the following **python** code:

```
for sel in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.l_post.j_l_post.l_post_bright'):
    for i in sel.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div[@class="lzl_cnt"]'):
        #user1 = i.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[@class="at j_user_card "]').text
        try: user2 = i.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="lzl_content_main"]/a[@username]').text
        except: user2 = ""
        text3 = ???

        print(user2, text3)
```

Comment: Can you update your HTML sample - it seem to be broken

Comment: @Andersson oh!Sorry

Comment: @YoarkYANG i have added an answer for you. Please try with that and let me know your feedback

Comment: Update your HTML sample once more: `a` node doesn't have a `@username` and `"text3"` is not a part of `a` node...

Comment: @Andersson Actually, a node does have ```@username```, (I did not write it out because I thought it is not relevant to the specific question, but if it seems confused you guys, so I will update them) and text3 is not part of a node,it is part of span node: text1, and text3 is part of span node, but they got split by an ```a node```

Comment: What I wanted to say is that `.../a[@username]').text` means that you search for `"text3"` inside `a` node, so I suggested that your HTML is incorrect

Comment: @Andersson That is for getting text2, I have changed text2 to "username", hope it is not confusing now, sorry for the trouble^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In selenium you cannot use XPath that returns attributes or text nodes, so `/text()` syntax is not allowed. If you want to get specific child text node  only instead of complete text content (returned by `text` property), you might execute JavaScript

You can apply below code to get required text node:

```
...
try: user2 = i.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="lzl_content_main"]/a[@username]').text
except: user2 = ""
span = i.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="lzl_content_main"]')
reply = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', span)
```

You might also need to do `reply = reply.strip()` to get rid of trailing spaces

Comment: edited the question, please have a look, and thank you!

Comment: Worked!, and also found more problem with my code ... though seemed solvable by myself, Thanks again! And time for me to learn some JS...

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
//div[@class='lzl_cnt']
```

And then you should use the `.text` on that element

Except you span isn't closed, so assuming it closes before the div.

Comment: It seem to be a Python - there is no such property as `getText`

Comment: Edited, now it is .text

Answer (score 0):

Here i am answering a solution for you.

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.tagName("span"));

    for(WebElement el : list){
        String desiredText = el.getAttribute("innerHTML");
        if(desiredText.equalsIgnoreCase("text3")){
            System.out.println("desired text found");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Please use the above code and let me know your feedback.

Comment: Sorry, I did not make it clear: I use python, thanks any ways

Comment: @YoarkYANG just use the logic. get all elements with tagname with span. then write a loop through the list and inside loop get the innerHTML value. if desired text found just braek